# When calling a interrupt 0x20 which is clock interrupt in 8259A, it jumes to 0xf000:fff0

Tags: c, assembly, x86-16

I am trying to write a microkernel. When I wanna jump from kernel to the first process, something wrong with clock interrupt. When code is still in kernel, i `sti` and `int 0x20` and code does jump to clock handler. After using `iret` to return the first process, I try `int 0x20` in the process, but it doesn't jump to clock handler and to f000:fff0.
FYI: the eflags is 0x1212 in the middle of the process. I stimulate x86 machine in bochs.
**I wanna know the reason why it counldn't jump to clock handler.**
If any more details are needed, please tell me.
Thanks for any responses in advance.

```
%include "const.inc"

extern  cstart          ;function
extern  gdtPos          ;global variable
extern  idtPos          ;global variable
extern  dispPos         ;global variable
extern  PCBready        ;global variable
extern  intReEnterFlag  ;global variable
extern  tss             ;global variable

global LABEL_TOPOFSTACK
global halt

[SECTION .bss]
LABEL_STACK_KERNEL:     resb        2*1024
LABEL_TOPOFSTACK:

[SECTION .text]
global _start

_start:
    mov esp,LABEL_TOPOFSTACK    ;LABEL_TOPSTACK=0x32800  ss=0x10
    mov dword [dispPos],0x00    ;label dispPos is 0x32800
    mov dword [intReEnterFlag],0x00
    sgdt [gdtPos];label gdtPos is 0x32c20
    call cstart
    lgdt [gdtPos]
    lidt [idtPos]                   ;label idtPos is 0x32804
    jmp MACRO_SelectorFlatC:csinit
csinit:                             ;0x08:0x3043a
;start the first process, recover the first process field
    mov ax,MACRO_SelectorTSS
    ltr ax
    mov esp,[PCBready]
    lldt [esp+MACRO_P_PCBSel]
    lea eax,[esp+MACRO_P_STACKTOP]
    mov dword [tss+MACRO_T_ESP0],eax

    dec dword [intReEnterFlag]
    pop gs
    pop fs
    pop es
    pop ds
    popad
    ;sti
    ;hlt
    add esp,4
    iretd
halt:
    int 0x20
    hlt
    ret
```

```c
#include "type.h"
#include "const.h"
#include "intVector.h"
#include "important.h"
#include "process.h"
#include "prototype.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "global.h"

void halt();
PUBLIC void TestA() { //0x05:0x30d01
    halt();
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        dispPos = 0;
        dispStr("A");
        dispInt(i++);
        dispStr(".");
    }
}
```

Comment: If the DPL of the interrupt gate is less than the CPL, the the INT instruction will #GP. Do you have a working #GP handler? If not, I would definitely get that working first. (Though I suppose Bochs should tell you if a GP occurred.)

Comment: `f000:fff0` is the reset vector, so this indicates the CPU resetting, which happens in case of a triple fault.  It does sound likely that something is wrong with your descriptor tables, so please show us those.  In fact, if possible please turn this into a [mcve] that somebody could actually build and run, without having to guess at how to fill in omitted code.

Comment: Thanks for your response.@prl And as you suppose, in the middle of the process, the cs is 0x05 whose RPL is 0x01. But i do have the #GP handler which works in RING0. When I debug the program in bochs using "s" which means it will enter the function body, it doesn't enter #GP handler and just jumps to 0xf000:fff0. I dont know why.
Could you tell me any probable cause?
Thanks for your any response in advance.

Comment: I set DPL of the interrupt gate to 3, but still cant ```int 0x20```.

Comment: Is the interrupt gate valid at all (e.g. does the CPL in the CS register in the gate match the CPL in the corresponding GDT entry...)?